# Not able to customize react-native-google-places-autocomplete. List view Is not clickable while overlap on another view

Tags: react-native

I have implemented the **react-native-google-places-autocomplete** on a view container which is drop-down view. The view of drop-down is overlapping on another container card view. I cannot be able to modify the **react-native-google-places-autocomplete** container perfectly and list view is not clickable while overlapping on another container down below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGpAh.png)

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                      placeholder="Eg., Andheri, Mumbai"
                      minLength={1} // minimum length of text to search
                      autoFocus={false}
                      returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
                      keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
                      listViewDisplayed="auto" // true/false/undefined
                      fetchDetails={true}
                      renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
                      onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                        // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                        console.log(data, details);
                      }}
                      getDefaultValue={() => ''}
                      query={{
                        // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                        key: 'AIzaSyD43CuzEHmrEAfkTFWckr2E5VTLTwyuPXE',
                        language: 'en', // language of the results
                        types: '(cities)', // default: 'geocode'
                      }}
                      styles={googleSearchInput}
                      //  currentLocation={true} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
                      // currentLocationLabel="Current location"
                      nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
                      GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={
                        {
                          // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
                        }
                      }
                      GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                        // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
                        rankby: 'distance',
                        type: 'cafe',
                      }}
                      GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
                        // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
                        fields: 'formatted_address',
                      }}
                      renderRightButton={() => (
                        <Image
                          style={{height:"30%",resizeMode:"contain" , alignSelf: 'center'}}
                          source={Images.searchIcon}
                        />
                      )}
                    />


const googleSearchInput = {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '60%',
    marginBottom: 0,
    borderRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.18,
    shadowRadius: 1.0,
  },
  description: {
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: '#00152b',
    opacity: 0.9,
  },
  poweredContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 0.2,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 33,
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    color: '#00152b',
    placeholderTextColor: 'red',
  },
  separator: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
};
```

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: Please see the question. I have edited once again with the code I have used for that

Comment: Please tell me how to remove border which Is on top of autocomplete and how to make elevation and rounded curve on the autocomplete card.